# Jquery .each loop for insert data to the class

Tags: asp.net, jquery

I have a simple issue ,I have a foreach loop in jQuery. What I want do is write the total price to the `<p class="fT"></p>` section like this (  `$(".fT").html(totalPrice);`   ) 
but everytime I write the same data to the fT class. How can I solve this problem?

```
$(document).ready(function () {
                        var totalPrice;
                        var pricerange = 1;
                        var day = 12;

                        $("p.pxclass").each(function (index, value) {

                            var f1 = parseFloat($(".f1",this).text());
                            var f2 = parseFloat($(".f2",this).text());
                            var f3 = parseFloat($(".f3", this).text());
                            var f4 = parseFloat($(".f4", this).text());
                            alert(f1);


                                if (pricerange == 1) {
                                    totalPrice = day * f1;

                                }
                                if (pricerange == 2) {
                                    totalPrice = day * f2;

                                }
                                if (pricerange == 3) {
                                    totalPrice = day * f3;

                                }
                                if (pricerange == 4) {
                                    totalPrice = day * f4;

                                }

                                $(this).find(".fT").html(totalPrice);

                                alert("total price:" + totalPrice);

                              });









                    });
                            </script>
```

This section repeats depending on the count in the database, 4 or 5 times

```
     <p class="pxclass">
                                  1-3 :   <p class="f1"> <%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem,"_Agfg.Fiyat1") %></p>   €
                                  4-7  :  <p class="f2"> <%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem,"_Agfg.Fiyat2") %></p>  €
                                 8-14 :   <p class="f3"><%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem,"_Agfg.Fiyat3") %></p>     €
                                  15-21+ :  <p class="f4"> <%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem,"_Agfg.Fiyat4") %></p>    €

                                  Total Price :   <p class="fT"></p>€
                                                      </p>

     <p class="pxclass">
                                  1-3 :   <p class="f1"> <%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem,"_Agfg.Fiyat1") %></p>   €
                                  4-7  :  <p class="f2"> <%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem,"_Agfg.Fiyat2") %></p>  €
                                 8-14 :   <p class="f3"><%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem,"_Agfg.Fiyat3") %></p>     €
                                  15-21+ :  <p class="f4"> <%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem,"_Agfg.Fiyat4") %></p>    €

                                  Total Price :   <p class="fT"></p>€
                                                      </p>

   <p class="pxclass">
                                  1-3 :   <p class="f1"> <%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem,"_Agfg.Fiyat1") %></p>   €
                                  4-7  :  <p class="f2"> <%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem,"_Agfg.Fiyat2") %></p>  €
                                 8-14 :   <p class="f3"><%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem,"_Agfg.Fiyat3") %></p>     €
                                  15-21+ :  <p class="f4"> <%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem,"_Agfg.Fiyat4") %></p>    €

                                  Total Price :   <p class="fT"></p>€
                                                      </p>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to target the `fT` element which is inside the current `pxclass` element, so either use a context based search like

```
$(".fT", this).html(totalPrice);
```

or use find

```
$(this).find(".fT").html(totalPrice);
```

Comment: var f1 = parseFloat($(".f1",this).text());
                                var f2 = parseFloat($(".f2",this).text());
                                var f3 = parseFloat($(".f3", this).text());
                                var f4 = parseFloat($(".f4", this).text()); this give me nan value

Comment: can you share a sample of generated html

Comment: <p class="f1"> 11,00</p>

Comment: The `,` is not a valid number format... also is there any empty elements

Comment: okey anur thank you so much fixed the problem ,it was my fault